# Vuetify Data-Table Header array not accepting empty child associations

Tags: javascript, arrays, ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a data-table using Vuetify that passes a localAuthority prop from a rails backend. It all works really well until I pass an empty child association (nested attribute).  In this case 'county':

```
<script>
  import axios from "axios";
  export default {
    name: 'LocalAuthorityIndex',
    props: {
      localAuthorities: {type: Array, default: () => []},
      counties: {type: Array, default: () => []},
      localAuthorityTypes: {type: Array, default: () => []}
    },
    data() {
      return{
        search: '',
        dialog: false,
        testmh: 'hello',
        dialogDelete: false,      
        headers: [
          { text: 'Name', align: 'start', value: 'name' },
          { text: 'ONS Code', value: 'ons_code' },
          { text: 'ID', value: 'id' },
          { text: 'Population', value: 'population' },
          { text: 'county', value: 'county.name' },
          { text: 'Website', value: 'website' },
          { text: 'Actions', value: 'actions', sortable: false },
        ],
```

So in the example above it works as long as all records have a county association (belongs_to).  However, if one record does not have a 'county' associated with it then I get the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"
```

I have tried lots of things like adding in a conditional statement like below:

```
      { text: 'county', value: ('county.name' ? 'county.name' : nil )},
```

But nothing seems to work.

Comment: Could you include your `<v-data-table>` component into your code and provide your vuetify version? I'm not experienced any warn/error in this case in latest vuetify 2.6.1 - similar unassociated columns just remains blank. It would also be nice if you could reproduce the problem at Codepen.

Comment: Here is a codepen of the vue file.  I am new to view and coding so I realise this is all a bit messy.  https://codepen.io/TomasMillar/pen/OJxyOev?editors=1010.  Rails is passing a local_authorities model that sometimes belongs to a county and sometimes doesn't.  vue version "^2.6.14",

Comment: Thanks your comments made me look elsewhere in the code and I figured out that the problem is actually in the first few lines where I'm trying to show that county name as a link to the county.  Still need to figure out how to solve this.  It feels like the answer is nothing to do with the title of my post so I wonder if I should delete this thread.  Not sure what is good etiquette?

Comment: These lines seemed to do the trick: 
<div v-if="item.county">
            {{ item.county.name }}
    </div>

Comment: I guess it's not a better solution to place v-if here... I'll post an answer and will try to explain how v-data-table headers and slots works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your `<v-data-table>` code at Codepen, I see that you are overriding default table item slots with your own.

Your error are from this part of code:

```
...
<template #item.county.name="{ item }">
  <a :href="'/counties/' + item.county_id">
    {{ item.county.name }}
  </a>
</template>
...
```

Take a look at first string. `#item.county.name` is a short form of `v-slot:item.county.name` and comes from one of your strings in `headers` array:

```
...
{ text: 'county', value: 'county.name' },
```

So there's no error, this part are correctly parsed by vuetify library even when your *item* will not contain any *county*.

The error is in 3rd string of the above code. You are trying to print *name* of *county* without checking its existence. That's why you are getting `...Cannot read properties of undefined...` error.

I guess you may fix your issue this way:

```
<template #item.county.name="{ item }">
  <a :href="'/counties/' + item.county_id">
    {{ item.county ? item.county.name : 'No name' }}
  </a>
</template>
```

Of course, if you need to hide your link to counties in this case, you may also add `v-if` (or `v-show`) into `a` tag.

I also created [a small Codepen](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/oNGjqgK) with some static data. Take a look into item.name.text slot in this playground, maybe it will help you to understand similar object associations.

Comment: Thank you so much... solved the problem and really helpful answer.